# configure login and password with jaas

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jaas

how can i configure jaas in JBOSS7 to authenticate user against File not against a database?
most of the configuration example use a RDBMS aproach to login , whilst my requirement is to authenticate user against a file.

i want to be able to feed the configuration below to Jboss and define my own LoginModule to validate submitted user password against the options defined in jaas configuration file .

```
  Example {
      myCustomLoginModule required
   user="admin"
   password="123"
   debug="true";
   };
```

EDIT : i found this to be very useful , apearently there's already a standard login module that authenticates against a file :

[example here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Login_Modules.html#exam-UsersRoleLoginModule)

[Documentation](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsersRolesLoginModule)

Comment: Yes there is. Most containers default to this